# MySql : how can I implement a sort of "read/not read yet" topics?

Tags: mysql

I'm about to implement a list of topic/argument in my forum, and I'd like to insert a sort of flag like "read/not read yet" for each message, regard each user in my website.

I think at somethings like this : a table `watched_topics` with `id(INT), user(VARCHAR)` and `topic_id(INT)`. When a `user` watch the page, I'll insert (if the data doesn't exist) these information.

When another `user` will insert a new message in a topic, I'll delete from the table `watched_topics` all line with that `topic_id`.

That could provide a trouble : Think about to **9000 topics** and **9000 users** that have watched all topics : the table will be so big (**9000x9000=81000000**).

So, I think is not the best strategy to implement this kind of stuff! Any suggestion would be appreciated :)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggestion sounds good. I would make user-field also a foreign key - it gives you a bit more flexibility.

Are you sure all 9000 topics are read by all 9000 users? I mean is this reality? Like you said, topic-entries are deleted when new message is added. And when that happens, another 9000 entries are deleted :)

I would index the table and go with your suggestion (with user_id change). If the table size gets in your way, you can always change the implementation later. Most likely it will never be the issue anyway.

Comment: Uhm yeah, but delete every time 9000 entries in a table of 81000000 records (for example) is a waste of resources :) And yes, the `user_id(INT)` will be more performant :)

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest a different approach?

**Make use of web browser history mechanism.**

Every topic can get a new, unique URL every time a new message is added there. It could include the number of messages, last modified time or a combination of both.

If the user did see the topic, he must have visited it, so a properly set up CSS can help identifying the read ones. You can even use some client-side scripts to modify the behaviour of the page based on that.

---

Another way to do that would be to keep the watched topics table the way you want to do it, but also store last visit time in user's profile and show all topics as read that haven't changed since that time.

---

However it's pretty safe to assume that all users reading all topics is very unlikely.

Comment: I like this approach: "Another way to do that would be to keep the watched topics table the way you want to do it, but also store last visit time in user's profile and show all topics as read that haven't changed since that time." This way you don't have to delete the 9000 entries :) - just compare the timestamps.

Comment: Thanks. :) That's actually how I've done in a forum script I wrote about 10 years ago. Now I'd do it using the browser history method and timestamps exclusively, probably making the client-side completely handle the appearance of read topics. That allows to cache the topics list on the server and reduce database load (if that ever becomes an issue).

Comment: But the first approch won't work if i delete the browser cache :)

Answer (score 1):

For the deletion: you could save what the latest msg-ID was the user saw. This way you do not have to perform a lot of delete actions every time a msg is posted in a much-viewed topic.

Comment: Uhm, like another field as "actual_delete"? So, without delete 9000 lines I'll update them changing that field?